# Trying to find all sequences from a user table

Tags: oracle

I've got the following sql statement which gives me an inconsistent datatypes: expected got LONG

```
select table_name, data_default from user_tab_columns where data_default like '%NEXTVAL%';
```

How can I get around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use like clause on long column , workaround from the same is to create a table by converting long CLOB.

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_user_tab_column AS
   SELECT to_lob(a.data_default) data_default, a.table_name FROM user_tab_columns a;
   
   
   select table_name, data_default from tbl_user_tab_column where data_default like '%NEXTVAL%';
```